# Instantiate C++ function using wstring instead of wchar_t

Tags: c++, function, wchar-t, wstring

I have a C++ overloaded function and one of its variants receives a wstring as a parametre, but when I call it like `myfunc(L"Some text")`, the compiler complains that there is no variant of the function which accepts `wchar_t *`.

What should I do?

LATER EDIT:

```
Lucru();
Lucru(short,short,short,short,wstring,wstring,wstring,wstring,wstring,wstring);
```

This is how the function looks in its declaration. As this suggests, it is a constructor function for a class...

Comment: `myfunc(std::wstring(L"Some text"));` ?

Comment: Works fine for me.  What compiler are you using?  What's the exact error message?  What other overloads does `myfunc` have?  Can you post a more complete example?

Comment: The [std::basic_string constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that accepts a character pointer is not `explicit` so `myfunc(L"Some text")` should work. Please post your function signatures and an example of how you're calling it. [Here's](http://ideone.com/My7iK) an example.

Comment: @Prætorian My function is actually an object constructor, one of whose variants has `wstring`s as some of its parameters.

Comment: @PetruDimitriu It doesn't matter, everything I've said still applies

Comment: @PetruDimitriu: Can you show the actual declaration for `myFunc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Construct the wide character string explicitly:

```
myFunc(std::wstring(L"text"));
```

Comment: @PetruDimitriu: That can't have been "it". The constructor for `std::wstring` is implicit, so `myFunc(L"text")` should also have worked, presuming that `myFunc` is indeed declared to take a `wstring` argument.

Comment: I've just posted the code in the question statement above. Nothing special.

Answer (score 1):

Change the function to accept `wstring` values by const reference:

```
Lucru(short,short,short,short,const wstring&,const wstring&,const wstring&,const wstring&,const wstring&,const wstring&);
```